# css/javascript start faded out by default, then fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, opacity, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to make a button that causes a green check image to fade in then fade out again. It mostly works, but how do I make the check start out in the faded out position when the page loads?

I tried to put `opacity: 0;` in its css, assuming that the fadeIn function changes the opacity, but then it doesn't show up at all.

```js
function green_check(check) { //fade in half a sec, hold 2 sec, fade out in 3 sec
  $(check).fadeIn(500, function() {
    $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut(3000);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="green_check(getElementById('check'));">Show Check</button>

<img class='five_sec_check' width="50" height="50" id="check" src='http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qcB/Bex/qcBBexbc5.png' />
```

Is there some other transparency property that fadeIn/fadeOut uses that I can set in the css before those are called? Or maybe prevent the opacity in the css from overriding the fadeIn function?

Thanks

Comment: "how do I make the check start out in the faded out position when the page loads?" Can you explain better please?

Comment: my goal was to have it invisible, then when the function is called it fades in to visible, then slowly goes invisible again. But my problem was keeping it invisible before the fade in is called without interfering with it. display: none worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use display:none in css to hide on page load:

```
#check {
  display:none;
}
```

```js
function green_check(check){ //fade in half a sec, hold 2 sec, fade out in 3 sec
    $(check).fadeIn(500, function () {
        $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut(3000);
    });
}
```

```css
#check {
  display:none;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="green_check(getElementById('check'));">Show Check</button>

<img class='five_sec_check' id="check" src='http://neil.computer/s/check.png'/>
```